# Wrapping GraphQL query inside JSON string to send a request to GraphQL endpoint

Tags: json, go, request, graphql, github-api

I am trying to send a request to a graphql endpoint. My problem is that

```
var jsonStr = []byte(`{ "query": "query { viewer { login } organization ( login:"org") { description } }" `) 

req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, bytes.NewBuffer(jsonStr))
```

Returns "Problem parsing JSON" and

```
var jsonStr = []byte(`{ "query": "query { viewer { login } }" `)

req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, bytes.NewBuffer(jsonStr))
```

Gives me back the desired response. I am assuming that this has to do with something like whitespace or double quotes, but I am unsure exactly how to fix this issue. The only reason I am encasing a GraphQL query inside JSON is because bytes.NewBuffer will throw an error if given anything other than a JSON string and I cannot make the httpRequest without first passing the string into bytes.NewBuffer. Thank you so much for whatever insight you can give me.

Comment: Your string is obviously invalid JSON, so it makes sense that the API complains about it. How to fix the issue is to use valid JSON. How to make that input valid JSON depends on your intention, which we don't know.

Answer (score 1):

The json in your `jsonStr` variable is invalid - the quotes within the "query" object need to be escaped.

You can manually escape them:

```golang
var jsonStr = []byte(`{ "query": "query { viewer { login } organization ( login:\"org\") { description } }" `) 

req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, bytes.NewBuffer(jsonStr))
```

Or, if I was writing this, I'd probably use JSON marshaling to construct this object to avoid needing to manually escape the JSON:

```golang
type QueryRequestBody struct {
    Query string `json:"query"`
}

func main() {
    var query = QueryRequestBody{
        Query: `query { viewer { login } organization ( login:"org") { description } }`,
    }
    jsonStr, err := json.Marshal(query)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, bytes.NewBuffer(jsonStr))
}
```